# Profiler is enabled after a maintenance flag is created - malware?

Tags: magento-1.9, security

It seems like the profiler on my site is automatically enabled after the site goes down in maintenance mode- Is there any reason why magento goes into maintenance mode and subsequently, the profiler is turned on?

Could it be some kind of malware or intrusion on the site?

Thank you!

Comment: I got an admin user created with the username "dkesystem". Do you know more info about it?

Comment: @maria i deleted the user, it seems like a backdoor account created by some malicious attack

Answer (score 0):

Recently I fixed same type of problem in one of my project.

I found there are some suspected files were created in public_html directory. Deleting those all suspected files, changing all the passwords and removing unwanted users from backend resolved our problem.

Comment: was the unwanted username something like "dkesystem"?

Comment: you can delete all the user account expect the accounts that you are aware.